# Make div appear one after another upon button submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the 2nd div to show for 3 seconds after clicking the submit button and the 3rd div to show after a certain time. I want the 2nd and 3rd div to show in the same height and width of the 1st div one after another.First the 2nd div shows up and after 3 sec 3rd div shows and returns to the first div All the divs are stacked inside the main container with position absolute to main container whose position is relative. This is to be done in JavaScript.

Any help?

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="first">
        <button onclick="somefunction()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container,.first,.second,.third{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.main-container{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.first,.second.third{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.first{
    background-color:red;
}

.second{
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}

.third{
    background-color:green;
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function start() {
  setTimeout("show_second()", 3000);
}

function show_second() {
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: so far i have tried to use `setTimeout()` function but i could not achieve what i want to by using it.@Sinstein

Comment: We can help with homework questions, but you need to show your attempt

Comment: This is not a homework question, right now i am trying to create a loader on submit within a form whose height and width is exactly the same as form. the two div (here 2nd and 3rd) contains bunch of animations and UX..i just want them to show up one after another.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you post your javascript we can likely help fix issues the code may have

Comment: in above case button onclick="start()". The js code is here`function start()
{
  setTimeout ( "show_second()", 3000 );
}

function show_second ( )
{
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "inline";
}` but this doesnot work at all. it only works with single setTimeout function which i cannot use to show the div one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the `setTimeout`s.

Also you are using `getElementById`, but you haven't given the elements IDs, just classes, so you'll need to add those too:

```js
function start() {
  setTimeout("show_second()", 3000);
}

function show_second() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout("show_third()", 3000);
}

function show_third() {
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.main-container,
.first,
.second,
.third {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.first,
.second.third {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

.third {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div id="first" class="first">
    <button onclick="start()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="second">
  </div>
  <div id="third" class="third">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work here but i still cannot get it work in my form. I would really appreciate if you have a look at my codepen. http://codepen.io/orzoon/pen/xqwbdz?editors=1010

Comment: There's no div with `id="container-second"` and you'll need to add `return false` to the submit button's `onclick` otherwise the form will get posted. Revised: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWGmExhttp://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWGmEx

Comment: Does that mean `return false` prevents the form inputs from getting sent but how can i send the form data and display the latter divs one after another. Upon removing `return false` i am being sent back directly to the form page without showing up the animations. should i do form validation and return true at the end to display the animations as the form inputs  get sent.

Comment: If you're having further problems it is best (and recommended) to post a new question. Include in it the code you have presently. Sorry I wasn't able to reply; there is only so much of my spare time that I can devote to helping people on SO